# Error al instalar Symfony 3 en VPS de DigitalOcean

Tags: php7

Tengo una VPS en DigitalOcean Centos7 php7.2. Al momento de instalar Symfony3 me arroja el siguiente error.

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

- Tienes que ir a

  vim /etc/php.ini
- y habilitar todas las extensiones que te pide en la captura de pantalla.
- reseteas php
- Vuelves a instalar